# Rspec after_save

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I have a function that checks whether a string variable is empty and fills it with a value if so. This method runs prefixed with `before_save`.

I want to write an rspec test for this. I have a model factory with the variable in concern blank. How do I test if the variable changed after save?

So far I have,

```
it 'should autofill country code' do
  empty_country_code = ''
  @store = Factory.build(:store, :country_code => empty_country_code)
  @store.save
  @store.country_code.should eql '1'
end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would initialize a new `Store` instance with the `Factory` and then test that saving the `store` changes the `country_code` as expected.

```
describe 'before_save' do
  let!(:store) { Factory.build(:store, :country_code => '') }

  it 'autofills the country_code' do
    expect { store.save }.to change { store.country_code }.from('').to(1)
  end
end
```

Note that this does not actually test that the feature is implemented in a  `before_save` callback. Instead, it tests that the behavior works as expected. This means you can change the implementation and as long as the behavior is the same the test would still pass.

Comment: Strange. I received this:
    NoMethodError:
       undefined method `country_code' for nil:NilClass

Comment: Did you copy the `subject...` line?

Comment: I did. I am prying my test to see what is going on. From what I've found, the store nested in the it statement is nil.

Comment: Apparently, it cannot read store unless it is initialized in the it statement. That's why there was a no method error.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to check whether the data update to database, you should get it from database again before test run into checkpoint.

For example, if set a `before_save` method and change `country_code` to `1` in it, you can do:

```
it 'should autofill country code' do
  empty_country_code = '99'
  @store = Factory.build(:store, :country_code => empty_country_code)
  @store.save
  expect(Store.find_by(id: @store.id).country_code).to eq("1")  ## data get from database again
  ## test for more, you can do:
  ## @new_store = Store.find_by(id: @store.id)
  ## @new_store.country_code += 100
  ## @new_store.save
  ## expect(Store.find_by(id: @store.id).country_code).to eq("1")
end
```

This operate ensure that data in database has refresh.